# How to compare .val() to number in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure what's wrong with my jQuery Code. For some reason it's not working.

I have a table with a td tag:

```
<td id="c">'.$data['criticality'].'</td>
```

My jQuery Code :

```
if (($("#c").val()) <= (3)){
    $(this).css("background-color" , "yellow");
}
```

Comment: Only form elements (e.g. input) have values, not table cells. Use `html()` or `text()`

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that. Thank you

Comment: try .text() instead of .val()

Comment: .text() didn't work. Thank you

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around your `3` in `(3)`? Also you will probably need to convert whatever content you get from your table cell from a string to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the value of the td you'll have to get using .text(), convert to a number and then compare.

```
if (parseInt($("#c").text()) <= 3)
{
    $("#c").css("background-color" , "yellow");
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uycfp30n/

Comment: I didn't did that.I am still trying to work on your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it first so it converts the string to an integer.

`parseInt($('#c').text(), 10)`